# Label expression problem?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, python-parser, expression

I am mapping the municipalities 911 numbers on our road network and built a simple python expression to find the lowest value between 2 fields.  Then it shows that value on the line followed by an arrow indicating direction of numbers ascending.

Spot checks revealed random segments that did not present the correct value.

If anyone can spot the problem, please let me know.

```
def FindLabel ( [L_FIRST], [R_FIRST] ):
    if [L_FIRST] < [R_FIRST]:
        return [L_FIRST] + '>'
    elif  [R_FIRST] < [L_FIRST]:
        return [R_FIRST] + '>'
```

Comment: Convert them to numbers using float or int. Label engine treats them as strings, e.g. "2">"11"

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please [edit] your question to include a sample of the values you have in your two fields (including some that aren't working), and details about your fields such as field type.

Answer (score 4):

As FelixIP has commented, the fields are possibly being assessed as text rather than as numbers.

To illustrate:

```
> x = "333"
> y = "44"
> if x > y:
>     print "yes"
> else:
>     print "no"
no
```

This is because when a string is assessed for order (or greater than / less than) it starts at the left, as if it's a word (text) being sorted.  `3` is less than `4` therefore `"333"` is less than `"44"`.  Or to use a text analogy, `LARGE` comes before `SMALL` when sorting alphabetically, therefore `LARGE < SMALL`!

To make it assess as numbers use `int()` or `float()` when assessing the two fields.

```
> x = "333"
> y = "44"
> if float(x) > float(y):
>     print "yes"
> else:
>     print "no"
yes
```

So in your code convert the strings to numeric to have these assess correctly

```
def FindLabel ( [L_FIRST], [R_FIRST] ):
    lf = float([L_FIRST])
    rf = float([R_FIRST])
    if lf < rf:
        return [L_FIRST] + '>'
    elif  rf < lf:
        return [R_FIRST] + '>'
```

Comment: Elit not really needed +1 you have patience